# How do I test to see if an application exists in $PATH?

Tags: shell, shell-script, posix

I'm trying to write all of my `sh` startup/env scripts to work with as much *DRY* and as much: "works on every *nix I clone it to", as possible. This means making sure that if I try to run code that's not there, that the code fails gracefully. To that end I need to be able to test if programs exist. I know how to test if a file exists, but I'm not sure how to test to see if an application is executable within the path. I'd rather use the $PATH, as some of these need to work on arch, ubuntu, and centos. Some might be installed in my homedir, on systems where I don't have root, others might not be installed, and others yet my be installed in system paths.

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/855954) is the one I have bookmarked for such questions.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [**`type commandname`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/type.html). This returns true if `commandname` is anything executable: alias, function, built-in or external command (looked up in `$PATH`). Alternatively, use [`command commandname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/command.html) which returns true if `commandname` is a built-in or external command (looked up in `$PATH`).

```
exists () {
  type "$1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
}
```

There are a few sh variants (definitely pre-POSIX; I know of `/bin/sh` under OSF1 ≤3.x and some versions of the Almquist shell found in early NetBSD versions and a few 20th-century Linux distributions) where `type` always returns 0 or doesn't exist. I don't think any systems shipped with these this millennium. If you ever encounter them, here's a function you can use to search in `$PATH` manually:

```
exists () { (
    IFS=:
    for d in $PATH; do
      if test -x "$d/$1"; then return 0; fi
    done
    return 1
) }
```

This function is generally useful if you want to exclude built-ins and functions and look up the name in `$PATH`. Most shells have a built-in for this, [**`command -v`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/command.html), though it's a relatively recent addition to POSIX (still optional as of POSIX:2004). It's basically a programmer-friendly version of `type`: it prints the full path for an executable in `$PATH`, the bare name for a built-in or function, and an alias definition for an alias.

```
exists_in_path () {
  case $(command -v -- "$1") in
    /*) return 0;;
    alias\ *) return 1;; # alias
    *) return 1;; # built-in or function
  esac
}
```

Ksh, bash and zsh also have `type -p` to look up only executables in `$PATH`. Note that in bash, the return status of `type -p foo` is 0 if `foo` is a built-in or function; if you want to test for an executable in `$PATH`, you need to check that the output is not empty. `type -p` is not in POSIX; for instance Debian's ash (which is `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu) doesn't have it.

Comment: @gilles, will this (or something similar) `if [ type keychain ]; then` not work? I get error `/home/xenoterracide/.zshrc:84: parse error: condition expected: type` I suppose I could write the function exists... I just thought this might be simpler in a sense...

Comment: @xenoterracide: Drop the brackets!

Comment: I think you are looking for `if type $APP >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then ...` You don't want the `[]`.

Comment: Bah, I knew I should have refreshed.  Beaten by Gilles again!

Comment: `type -p` if you're specifically looking for a command in `$PATH` (not aliases or functions or builtins).

Comment: @ephemient: `type -p` isn't portable, and a bit strange in bash (see my edit).

Comment: `type -P` in bash if specifically looking for a command in $PATH (not aliases or functions or builtins). Added in [bash 2.05b](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2002-07/msg00005.html). _Admittedly, this isn't portable, which is what the OP wanted._

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for external programs, you can also use which. Don't know how portable that is though.

Comment: In theory, it's less portable than `type` or `command`; `which` is not in POSIX, for instance. In practice, `which` does exist almost everywhere, but in some places (where it's implemented as a csh script) it uses a different path (due to a `.cshrc`), which defeats the purpose.