# What is the best method to test if a program exists for a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, posix, lsb

I'm just curious to know how to best check if a program exists. I've seen solutions with

- `test`
- `command`
- `hash`
- `type`
- `which`
- `[`

Which is the best method, is there a *right* answer? What does the POSIX and LSB specs say about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want to use the `command` command, e.g.:

```
command -v <the_command>
```

For more discussion see the following StackOverflow posts:

- [Find out if a command exists on POSIX system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762631/find-out-if-a-command-exists-on-posix-system)
- [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Also see the following Unix StackExchange post:

- [How do I test to see if an application exists in $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/how-do-i-test-to-see-if-an-application-exists-in-path)

Comment: Thanks but this a dupe of this, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/85250#85250

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yeah, I just saw that. Well... problem solved!